# Is it possible to change Icon according to lightTheme or darkTheme in ThemeData? in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, icons

I want the icon to change and the boxshadow color to change when GestureDetecotr is pressed. hopefully it will be What should I do?

In the current emulator, press the middle button to change the appearance.

[blackMode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4cnrl.png)

[lightMode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10U37l.png)

#### home.dart part

```dart
              import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:neumorphism/theme/theme_service.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool _tapped = false;
    var _lightIcon = Icons.wb_sunny;
    var _blackIcon = Icons.dark_mode;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Neumorphism'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              ThemeService().changeThemeMode();
            },
            child: Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey[300],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(40),
                    ),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                          offset: Offset(5.0, 5.0),
                          blurRadius: 15.0,
                          spreadRadius: 1.0),
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          offset: Offset(-5.0, -5.0),
                          blurRadius: 15.0,
                          spreadRadius: 1.0),
                    ]),
                child: Center(child: Icon(_lightIcon)))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### themes.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Themes {
  final lightTheme = ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    primaryColor: Colors.grey[300],
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      brightness: Brightness.light,
    ),
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white, size: 80),
  );
  final darkTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    primaryColor: Colors.grey[800],
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
    ),
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(
      color: Colors.black87,
      size: 80,
    ),
  );
}
```

#### theme_service.dart

[theme_service.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVppj.png)

Answer (score 1):

Hello its easy to do this.
Your main problem is that you need to change the icons when the button is pressed. Right?

Then for this you have to use a **Stateful Widget** and then wrap the widget into a **Value Listenable Builder**. After that in onpressed you need to update the notifier.

Let's take a example....
Suppose you have to change the background color of the container when theme changed then do like this..

> First create a Instance of value Notifier.

```
ValueNotifier<bool> _themeNotifier = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);
```

> And then update the notifier in onpressed like this:-

```
onPressed:(){
      _themeNotifier.value = false ; //update the value
 }
```

> Note that i have used **bool** as a datatype of value notifier but you can choose whatever suits your need.

> Then Wrap your widget in a ValueListnablebuilder

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: _themeNotifier,
        builder: (context, value, child){
          return Container(
                   decoration:BoxDecoration(color:_themeNotifier.value ? Color.white : Color.black),
                   child: Container(), 
          )
        },
      ),
```

> Similar to this in you case you need to change the icon and boxshadow
> according to the value of the notifier.

**If you need any further explanation or help then you can comment.**

and as always
Happy Coding...

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. First of all what I tried is `bool isTaped = false;` so `onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                isTaped = !isTaped;
              });`

 setState was handled with . It was easier than I thought to do this, but I will try the method you told me. Thank you very much for your kind reply.

Comment: Set state is a powerful callback but its also very expensive because it will rebuild the whole tree especially when you have lots of things depend on state so its better to use value listnable to update minor thing.

Comment: Anyways if this answer helped you don't forget to up vote and accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

you also need to change the brightness of context  along with theme mode

Answer (score 0):

Check your theme's brightness to change icon and shadows.

To change the icon, you can use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/advanced_icon). Install the package in your project, import it in your file and then simply replace the `child` of your `container` with the below code:

```
AdvancedIcon(
  icon: Icons.wb_sunny,
  secondaryIcon: Icons.dark_mode,
  state: Theme.of(context).brightness==Brightness.dark ? AdvancedIconState.secondary : AdvancedIconState.primary,
)
```

Now to change shadow of the container, just replace the `boxShadow` of your `container`'s decoration with below code:

```
// replace the shadow with your values.
Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark ? [BoxShadow(color: Colors.white)] : [BoxShadow(color: Colors.black)]
```